# Make flexbox child fill available vertical space with flex-direction: row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Because a link to jsfiddle speaks a hundred words, here is what I am attempting to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/5zs823L9/7

Basically, I want the children in my flexbox to stretch and fill all the vertical space available in their row, but I can't seem to figure out how to do so. For example in this situation:

```
.flexcontainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexchild {
    flex-basis: 140px;
    flex-grow: 2;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexchild.first {
    min-height: 128px;
    height: 256px;
}

.flexchild.second {
    min-height: 128px;
}
```

In this situation, how can I get `flexchild.second` to stretch out and be 256 pixels high? (the height of `.flexchild.first` being dynamic in reality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `align-items: flex-start;` from `.flexcontainer`

```css
.flexcontainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* align-items: stretch; */ /* default */
}

.flexchild {
  display: block;
    position: relative;
    flex-basis: 140px;
    flex-grow: 2;
    vertical-align: sub;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flexchild first">
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9
  </div>
  <div class="flexchild second">
    this should be as high as the red child
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can set `align-self: stretch;` for `.second`

```css
.flexcontainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexchild {
  display: block;
    position: relative;
    flex-basis: 140px;
    flex-grow: 2;
    vertical-align: sub;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  background-color: blue;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flexchild first">
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9
  </div>
  <div class="flexchild second">
    this should be as high as the red child
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The children of a *flexbox* have the same height by default (`align-items: stretch`). Just remove `align-items: flex-start`.

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexchild {
  flex-basis: 140px;
  flex-grow: 2;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  background-color: blue;
}

.list.unstyled {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flexchild first">
    <ul class="list unstyled">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="flexchild second">
    this should be as high as the red child
  </div>
</div>
```

(Unnecessary *code* removed. Inserted a `ul` instead of multiple `<br>s`.)